# why does $(33^{40})^{111}33^4\equiv 33^4$ (mod 100)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> $(33^{40})^{111}33^4\equiv 33^4$ (mod 100)

does $m=\frac{(33^{40})^{111}}{100}$ where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Do you know what [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) or the Chinese remainder theorem are?

Comment: I know Euler theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $\gcd(33,100)=1$, therefore by Euler's theorem, $33^{\phi(100)}\equiv1\pmod{100}$.

And guess what? $\phi(100)=40$...

Answer (score 4):

Because by Euler's theorem, $33^{40}\equiv 1$, which means that $$(33^{40})^{111}\cdot 33^4\equiv 1^{111}\cdot 33^{4}=33^4\pmod{100}$$